# Question about message loop

Tags: windows, multithreading, operating-system

I have a question haunting me for a long time.

Short version:

What's the working paradigm of Windows Message Loop?

Detailed version:

When we start a Windows application (not a console application), we can interact with it through mouse or keyboard. The application retrieve all kinds of messages representing our movements from its meesage queue. And it is Windows that is responsible for collecting our actions and properly feeding messages into this queue. But doesn't this scenario mean that Windows has to run **infinitively**?

I think the ***Windows scheduler*** should be running all the time. It could possibly be invoked by a time interrupt at a pre-defined interval. When the scheduler is trigged by the time interrupt, it swithes current thread for the next pending thread. A single thread can only get its message with [GetMessage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644936%28VS.85%29.aspx) when it is scheduled to run.

I am wondering if there's only one Windows application running, will this application got more chance to get its message?

### Update - 1  (9:59 AM 11/22/2010)

Here is my latest finding:

According to < Windows via C/C++ 5th Edition > Chapter 7 Section: Thread Priorities

> ...For example, if your process'
>   primary thread calls GetMessage() and
>   the system sees that no messages are
>   pending, the system suspends your
>   porcess' thread, relinquishes the
>   remainder of the thread's time slice,
>   and immediately assigns the CPU to
>   another waiting thread.
>
> If no messages show up for GetMessage
>   to retrieve, the process' primary
>   thread stays suspended and is never
>   assigned to a CPU. However, when a
>   message is placed in the thread's
>   queue, the system knows that the
>   thread should no longer be suspended
>   and assigns the thread to a CPU if no
>   higher-priority threads need to
>   execute.

My current understanding is:

In order for the system to know when a message is placed in a thread's queue, I can think of 2 possible approaches:

1 - **Centralized approach**: It is the system who is responsible to always check **EVERY** thread's queue. Even that thread is blocked for the lacking of messages. If any message is availabe, the system will change the state of that thread to schedulable. But this checking could be a **real burden** to the system in my opinion.

2 - **Distributed approach**: The system doesn't check every thread's queue. When a thread calls GetMessage and find that no message is available, the system will just change the thread's state to blocked, thus not schedulable any more. And in the future no matter who places a message into a blocked thread's queue, it is this "**who**"(not the system) that is responsible to change the the thread's state from **blocked** to **ready** (or whatever state). **So this thread is dis-qualified for scheduling by the system and re-qualified by someone else in the regard of GetMessage**. What the system cares is just to schedule the **runable** threads. The system doesn't care where these schedulable threads come from. This approach will avoid the burden in approach 1, and thus avoid the possible bottleneck.

In fact, the key point here is, how are the states of the threads changed? I am not sure if it is really a *distributed paradigm* as shown in appraoch 2, but could it be a good option?

Comment: I want to start a bounty, but I cannot see the start bounty button yet.

Comment: If some moderator could help me start a bounty, please do that. Thanks.

Comment: You do not see the "start a bounty" button because you already have a bounty open. (See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56703/why-cant-i-start-a-bounty-on-this-question/56707#56707)

Answer (score 2):

Applications call `GetMessage()` in their message loop. If the message queue is empty, the process will just block until another message becomes available. Thus, `GetMessage` is a processes' way of telling Windows that it doesn't have anything to do at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So how is the "block" logic implemented? I am wondering whether or not the thread that is executing GetMessage() just busily loops polling for the message until it is scheduled away by the operating system?

Comment: Some adding: is this some kind of **spin lock**?

Comment: @smwikipedia: It is scheduled away. OS kernels have various methods for blocking, and spin locks are only used if the lock is expected to become free within a very short time, which makes no sense for GetMessage, as it can be minutes or hours until the next message for a particular process.

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering if there's only one
>   Windows application running, will this
>   application got more chance to get its
>   message?

Well yeah probably, but I think you might be missing a crucial point. Extracting a message from the queue is a blocking call. The data structure used is usually referred to as a blocking queue. The dequeue operation is designed to voluntarily yield the current thread's execution if the queue is empty. Threads can stay parked using a various different methods, but it is likely that thread remains in a waiting state using kernel level mechanisms in this case. Once the signal is given that the queue has items available the thread may go into a ready state and the scheduler will start assigning its fair share of the CPU. In other words, if there are no messages pending for that application then it just sits there in an idle state consuming close to zero CPU time.

Comment: Thanks for your post. I have added my comment to Ringding's reply. And I am curious about how a **blocking queue** is implemented? **And even with a blocking queue, there MUST be someone who always monitors the queue in my opinion. Otherwise, who knows something is enqueued? And doesn't this imply some kind of busy polling?**

Comment: You are definitely askking the right questions. I have to be honest, I don't know how the kernel level blocking mechanisms work. However, if I were to create a blocking device at the application level I would use the slow polling technique in conjunction with an API that causes the thread to yield its time slice. The polling would be frequent enough to be responsive within a few milliseconds, but slow enough to consume near zero CPU time. Again, the kernel level mechanisms might use an entirely different strategy. It would be interesting to know what it is huh?

Answer (score 0):

The fewer *threads* you have running (time slices are scheduled to threads, not processes), the more chances any single application will have to pull messages from its queue. Actually, this has nothing to do with Windows messages; it's true for all multithreading; the more threads of the same or higher priority which are running, the fewer time slices any thread will get.

Beyond that, I'm not sure what you are really asking, though...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will refine my question later.